# Delete one type of file from specific directory however not from subdirectory

Tags: hp-ux, deleted-files

I am currently working on HP-UX and have a cron job which runs every morning which deletes file older than certain number of days based on retention policy. Recently I added a sub directory at the path from where file was getting deleted and wanted to have a different policy for files residing under this sub directory.

Currently my command is as below:

```
find /directory/backup -mtime +1 -name "FileName*.EXT" -exec rm {} \;
```

When this command runs it deletes all the files under backup directory as well as any matching file inside sub directory of backup. I meant there is another directory called backup_db inside backup directory.

```
pwd
/directory/backup/backup_db
```

I want to restrict deletion from backup directory only and not from sub directory. How can I achieve that? Any help is highly appreciated.

I tried *man rm* however didn't find anything which could be of my help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your command line, the `find` command will produce a series of individual `rm` commands and execute them. Each `rm` command will delete one file, specified with a full pathname. So it is not the `rm` you need to restrict, but the `find`.

The syntax to do this can be a bit tricky, for historical reasons.
You could do it like this:

```
find /directory/backup ! -path /directory/backup -prune -mtime +1 -type f -name "FileName*.EXT" -exec rm {}\+
```

The `find $DIR ! -path $DIR -prune <desired_conditions> [desired_action]` is the POSIX-compatible way to restrict `find` to a single directory. But it will still list the names of sub-directores of that particular directory, unless you add further conditions.

Using `-type f` will restrict `find` from attempting to generate `rm` commands for sub-directories in the backup directory, which would just create useless error messages: to delete a directory, you'd need a recursive `rm` or `rmdir`, and I understood that's something you don't want to do in this case.

Replacing the semicolon at the end of the command specification for `-exec` with a plus sign will improve performance if there are a lot of files to delete: instead of generating one `rm` command per file, it will generate as few commands as possible, stuffing as many pathname arguments onto each `rm` command as the command line length allows. This drastically reduces the need to `fork()` new processes.

Comment: With above command, I got error for semi colon as --> find: -exec not terminated with ';'

Comment: Well, the semicolon will also work but with reduced efficiency. The HP-UX `find(1)` man page says: "In the UNIX 2003 environment, + indicates end of cmd, only if + immediately follows {}." The problem might also be an extra space or a matter of quoting specific to the shell you're using.

Comment: Didn't get your point. In the answer above, we have rm {}\+. So, you want to change it to rm {}+

Comment: Maybe, depending on how your shell (`sh`? `ksh`? `bash`? `tcsh`? some-other-sh?) handles the plus sign. The standard `find` command of HP-UX 11.31 is definitely documented to handle the plus sign.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with `rm` but with `find`. Use the `-maxdepth 0` option to limit the search to the starting directory.

If `-maxdepth` is not supported by your version of `find` you can also exclude directories with `-path` and `-prune`:

> To  ignore  a whole directory tree, use -prune rather than checking every file in the tree.  For example, to skip the  directory `src/emacs'  and  all  files  and directories under it, and print the names of the other files found, do something like this:
>
> find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print

Comment: As far as I know, HP-UX `find` does not have the `-maxdepth` option.

Comment: I am using HP-UX Itanium(B.11.31 U)